# Jetpack Compose: Backend Internal error when calling function with lambda from Coroutine

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Sort of strange one but was getting "Backend Internal error" error when using Jetpack Compose and turned out it was triggered by calling a function that takes a lambda from within a Coroutine.

It's pretty easy to reproduce....have narrowed it down to following steps:

Create new project using "Empty Compose Activity" template.  Update to dev07 (had issue with previous versions as well) and also add following to `build.gradle`

```
composeOptions {
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "0.1.0-dev07"
}
```

Add following to `MyActivity.kt`

```
fun someFun(success: (String) -> Unit) {
}
```

and then update `onCreate` to following:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    lifecycleScope.launch {
        someFun {
        }
    }
    setContent {
        MaterialTheme {
            Greeting("Android")
        }
    }
}
```

Build project and then you see following error:

```
e: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Backend Internal error: Exception during code generation
Element is unknownThe root cause java.lang.RuntimeException was thrown at: org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.FunctionCodegen.generate(FunctionCodegen.kt:42)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.CompilationErrorHandler.lambda$static$0(CompilationErrorHandler.java:35)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmBackendFacade.doGenerateFilesInternal$backend_jvm(JvmBackendFacade.kt:114)
```

Note you also need to add following dependency to `build.gradle`

```
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.2.0"
```

Comment: AFAIK, Jetpack Compose and coroutines don't work together at the moment. That will work in the long term, just not right now.

Comment: Had seen something about that but what confused me was that it seems like other scenarios are working e.g. calling suspend function from viewModelScope in ViewModel.  Issue seems to only happen if passing lambda (e.g. if using collect() or just basic example shown here)

Comment: Perhaps coroutines are fine in Kotlin files that do not contain calls to `@Composable` functions like `MaterialTheme()` or `Greeting()`.

Comment: The original issue had all such calls in separate file....this was somewhat fabricated example in this post just to illustrate minimum needed to see issue.

Comment: I'm facing the same error in my project, but I do not have a function in my activity/fragment that takes a lambda. Maybe a 3rd party dependency brings it in though?

Comment: Did you already create an official issue ticket for it? If so, pls link it :)

Comment: Probably unrelated, but I was getting "backend internal" errors when I didn't enable compose in build.gradle (buildFeatures.compose=true)

Answer (score 33):

Make sure to add this to every module you use compose in

```
buildFeatures {
    compose true
}
```

This was a comment by alashow and the only thing that worked.

Answer (score 10):

Make sure that you have added compose to your Gradle inside `android {...}` block. You have to do it for every module that uses compose. Refer following to add the compose:

```
buildFeatures {
    compose = true
}

composeOptions {
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_version
}
```